# Calling a Slot by QtCore.SignalMapper

Tags: python, pyqt4, signals-slots

I want to check the users input in several QtGui.QLineEdits by the same function with different parameters. I tried QtCore.SignalMapper. This is my code in a test-application:

```
    self.signalMapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.lineEdit_331, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8('returnPressed()')), self.signalMapper.map)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.lineEdit_341, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("returnPressed()")), self.signalMapper.map)
    self.signalMapper.setMapping(self.lineEdit_331,'links')
    self.signalMapper.setMapping(self.lineEdit_341,'rechts')
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.signalMapper, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("mapped(QString)")),self.test)
```

The signalMapper exists and all connects return 'True' but the slot isn't called (the same after changing the order of 'connect' and 'setMapping').
Connecting the lineEdits signals to the slot works:

```
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.lineEdit_331, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("returnPressed()")), self.test_1)
```

what's wrong in my code? Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing wrong with your code, is that you are using the ugly, error-prone, old-style syntax for connecting signals, instead of the [new-style syntax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html).

Here is a re-write of your example code:

```
    self.signalMapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)
    self.lineEdit_331.returnPressed.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
    self.lineEdit_331.returnPressed.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
    self.signalMapper.setMapping(self.lineEdit_331, 'links')
    self.signalMapper.setMapping(self.lineEdit_341, 'rechts')
    self.signalMapper.mapped[str].connect(self.test)
```

If you're curious why your original code didn't work, it's because you should have used SLOT in the first two connections. It should have been:

```
    QtCore.QObject.connect(
        self.lineEdit_331, QtCore.SIGNAL('returnPressed()'),
        self.signalMapper, QtCore.SLOT('map()'))
```

This is because there are two overloads of [QSignalMapper.map](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html#map), so you would have needed to specify which one you intended to use.

Comment: Your re-Write in new-style syntax works, thanks for your tip, the old style-syntax completed as described by you does not. Before using old-style syntax i tried new-style without success. You provided the explanation: i forgot '[str]' in the last line.

Comment: @user3455890. Curious. I tested the exact code in your question and using SLOT is the only thing that fixes it for me. But maybe it depends on the version of pyqt/sip, or something...

Comment: I think, it's the Qstring in the last connect, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400858/how-to-create-qstring-in-pyqt4. I added the 'Try / Except' to my test-application and it works. So the most important hint was Your '[str]', thanks for your support, and from now I use the new-style syntax :-)