# How to convert stringVar() from tk to pyqt

Tags: python, tkinter, pyqt

I have this function as part of my code and I am trying to move from tk to pyqt, but I do not have much experience in pyqt. I am trying to generate a list of Tkinter string variables to store the entries.

```
def generate_stringvars(self):
    temp_entriesx = []
    count = 0
    while count < 21:
        e = tk.StringVar()
        e.set("")
        temp_entriesx.append(e)
        count += 1
    return temp_entriesx
```

How do I change **tk.StringVar()** to make it work in pyqt?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few differences between pyQt and Qt. One important difference is that there is no explicit need for QString ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2595514/1124661)). pyQt is fully compatible with Python built-in string type. Your code will look something like this.

```
def generate_stringvars(self):
    temp_entriesx = []
    count = 0
    while count < 21:
        temp_entriesx.append("")
        count += 1
    return temp_entriesx
```

Comment: I get an error, **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'**, for this line now, **i.set(entries[i_count])**. Do you know how I can fix it? @buck54321

Comment: @prexos seeing that is a separate question you should ask a new question. No one can answer your comment question without seeing the code. That said the error is telling your that `i` is a string object and not your `StringVar()` that it sounds like you think it is.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Thanks for your reply. I will post my question once the time limit passes.