# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set' error in python pyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I have this code:

```
self.entriesx = self.generate_stringvars()

# Fill in the entry fields if a template is selected.
def autofill(self):
    # Generate a dictionary of all the saved templates.
    test_dictionary = self.build_test_dictionary()
    # Retrive the selected qual name from the form.
    self.coded_entry = self.comboBox.currentText()
    entries = test_dictionary[self.coded_entry]
    # Set each entry field in self.entriesx to the corresponding value
    # from the template.
    i_count = 0
    for i in self.entriesx:
        i.set(entries[i_count])
        i_count += 1
    # Reload the entry fields with their new values.
    self.add_entry_fields()
```

The **autofill(self)** function automatically fills in the respective entries into entry fields based on a chosen item from a combo box. The autofill function also relies on this function:

```
# Generate a list of string variables to store the entries.
def generate_stringvars(self):
    temp_entriesx = []
    count = 0
    while count < 21:
        temp_entriesx.append("")
        count += 1
    return temp_entriesx
```

When I compile my code I get an error **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'** for **i.set(entries[i_count])** in my autofill function. How do I fix it?

**Edit:**
This is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50951872/how-to-convert-stringvar-from-tk-to-pyqt) post.

Comment: @eyllanesc The post you think is a duplicate is mine. I was told to post the above question in a new post. That is why I used some of the previous question again.

Comment: The previous question should cover the conversion of stringVar (tkinter) to str (PyQt), so I do not know why they told you that. but for me to separate a question in 2 unnecessarily is not correct. The title of your previous question should be sufficient for both questions, it is the same objective, read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the confused, this is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50951872/1124661). OP is trying to port from Tkinter to pyQt.

Tkinter's `StringVar` has a different interface than python `str`. Assignment is done using the assignment operator (`=`). Also, as a general rule, try not to use `i` or similar for non-integers types. It's not wrong, just bad coding practice. Also, since you no longer need the element itself. Just use `range`.

```
for i in range(len(self.entriesx)):
    self.entriesx[i] = entries[i]
```

Comment: Thanks again! Very helpful explanation.